# How to make searchfield appear on button itself in dropdown button flutter using dropdown_search

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using DropdownSearch from dropdown_search package in my flutter app. But, when I enable searchfield, it comes below the button. I want that the search option should be on that button only, ho can i achieve that?